# Loaded and overloaded constructors

Tags: java

Just curious, but I've been thinking a lot about constructors lately and I keep seeing loaded constructors and overloaded constructors.

I know that a loaded constructor is simply a constructor with parameters, and overloaded constructors are self explanatory. But is there really any difference between a loaded constructor and an overloaded constructor, or are there some small nuances that I didn't consider?

Comment: Overloaded constructors means you have multiple constructors for the same class, taking different arguments. I've never heard of "loaded constructors" before.

Comment: Where is the source of "loaded constructor", i just heard about overloading and overriding constructor... i am curious too

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I mean that the pages that my instructor provides me keep using the term "Loaded Constructors", and I tried searching up the term though it doesn't really help to explain it, if it even is a term...

Comment: Your instructor has created a term that does not exist. The correct term for the concept that I think is meant is "non-default constructor".

Answer (score 3):

I've never actually heard them referred to as "loaded" constructors before, but the only thing that differentiates them from the no-argument constructor (i.e. the one with no parameters) is that if a loaded constructor is defined explicitly and a no-argument constructor is not, then the default constructor (which has no arguments) won't exist and can't be used.

"Overloaded" is a term that can apply to *all* methods, not just to constructors. A method is *overloaded* if there's more than one definition/implementation, and the definitions have different method signatures. One example of an overloaded constructor in the standard library is the `String` constructor - all of the following are defined, and have slightly different behavior to handle their particular arguments:

```
String()  // default constructor
String(byte[] bytes)
String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, Charset charset)
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, String charsetName)
String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)
String(char[] value)
String(char[] value, int offset, int count)
String(int[] codePoints, int offset, int count)
String(String original)
String(StringBuffer buffer)
String(StringBuilder builder)
```

[The `String` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) also has plenty of overloaded methods that are not the constructor, including `.contentEquals()`, `.lastIndexOf()`, `.regionMatches()`, `.replace()`, `.split()`, `.startsWith()`, `.substring()`, `toUpperCase()`, `.toLowerCase()`

The term "overloaded" has nothing in particular to do with the term "loaded", in this context, and I'm pretty sure your instructor made "loaded" up. If they tell you to, use it anyway when they want you to - no sense annoying them over a meaningless semantic issue like this.

Comment: It isn't really correct to say "the default constructor is not allowed to be used" in that case, rather, the no-arg constructor simply doesn't exist in that case. You can never use any constructor that doesn't exist.

Comment: Your terminology is slightly off here in a way that is important: A [default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) is one that is not written in the code, not merely a _no-argument constructor_; `String()` is no-argument but not default.